# How to test if a JS library has loaded, using a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a simple dependency loader, and I'm having trouble while testing against the libraries to see if the initial load was successful or not. The primary hurdle seems to be due to my storing of the var name for each library as a string.

```
var libraries = [
    {
        libvar: 'jQuery',
        cdn: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js',
        fileName: 'jquery-2.1.4.min'
    }, {
        libvar: '_', // Underscore.js
        cdn: '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js',
        fileName: 'underscore-1.8.3.min'
    }
];

var checkLoad = function(library) {
    if (!library || !library.fileName.length) return;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var thisLib = eval(library.libvar);
        if (!thisLib) {
            script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', 'js/fallback/' + library.fileName + '.js');
            script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            document.body.appendChild(script);

            console.warn(library.libvar + ' loaded via fallback', thisLib); // Testing
        } else {
            console.warn(library.libvar + ' is loaded!'); // Testing
        }
    });
};

for (var i = 0; libraries.length > i; i++) {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + libraries[i].cdn + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    checkLoad(libraries[i]);
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

... where "jQuery" is simply the name of eval(library.libvar) for the link that I've manually broken.

The initial load and test works fine IF the script was loaded successfully from the cdn. But if I manually break cdn link, the script is suppose to attempt the fallback but instead is throwing a js error and halting.

I'm struggling to figure out how to write an appropriate test that will fail correctly without thowing an error and halting everything.

---

Per dbrin's solution, the fixed DOMContentLoaded function looks this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (!window[library.libvar]) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', 'js/fallback/' + library.fileName + '.js');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
});
```

Comment: you aren't putting `.js` on `fileName`.

Comment: what JS error are you getting

Comment: @DanielA.White - That was a copy/paste mistake that I've fixed. Also added my error msg to the question.

Comment: why not wrap your `eval` in a try/catch block?

Comment: Oh and eval is evil according to JSLint

Comment: @DanielA.White - I did rewrite it using try/catch and it worked, but I prefer dbrin's solution below more as it allows me to ditch the eval method altogether. Thnx though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
if(window['jQuery']) {
  // Hooray jQuery is loaded!
}
```

Comment: Or in this case (and with one less typo): `if (window[library.libvar]) {`

Comment: Funny.. I swear I tried this already and it failed. But apparently it failed for some other reason I can't recall, because works like a dream now. And allows me to scrap the eval method too.

Answer (score 0):

Noting how (in general) the library root objects become properties of the global `window` object, I would suggest you do something like:

```
var thisLib = eval("window." + library.libvar);
```

That way the if checks shouldn't fail.

Comment: use of eval raises red flag by JsLint

Comment: No need for `eval`. Just do `typeof window.library.libvar === 'undefined'`.